# Stopping erroneous input from socket when initializing menu

Tags: java, input, telnet

I am working on building my first telnet server. I can connect to it but for some reason it automatically fails out on the menu on the first connection. As soon as you connect it says the welcome message and then immediately states that my first input was not a viable option and to try again. Then it allows me to make my next selection correctly.

How do I prevent java from seeing any initial input and to wait until the user actually presses a key to begin accepting input from the user?

My code --

```
public class Sample_server {

  private static int port=4444, maxConnections=5;
  // Listen for incoming connections and handle them
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i=0;

    try{
      ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
      Socket server;

      while((i++ < maxConnections) || (maxConnections == 0)){
        doComms connection;
        server = listener.accept();
        doComms conn_c= new doComms(server);
        Thread t = new Thread(conn_c);
        t.start();
      }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}

class doComms implements Runnable {
    private Socket server;
    private String line,input;

    doComms(Socket server) {
      this.server=server;
    }

    public void run () {

      //input="";

      try {
        // Get input from the client
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
        out.println("You have connected to the server.");
        out.println("Welcome.");
        try {
            MenuSystemClass newMenu = new MenuSystemClass();
            newMenu.MainMenu(in, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start the menu");
        }

        // Now write to the client
        System.out.println("Overall message is:" + input);

        server.close();
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IOException on socket listen: " + ioe);
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

My Menu Code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sample_server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * My Custom Menu Class
 * @author aaron
 */
public class MenuSystemClass {

    public void MainMenu(DataInputStream in, PrintStream out) {
        // Set Run Boolean to true
        boolean running = true;
        // We switch the input to lowecase here and compare
        while(running) {
            out.println("A: New Char ; V: View ; W: Start Game; S: Save ; D: Delete ; Q: Quit");
            // Initialize the scanner
            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(in);
            // Get the user input
            String decision = user_input.next();
            // Conver their decision to lowercase and compare to choices.
            switch (decision.toLowerCase()) {
                case "a":
                    out.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "s":
                    out.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "d":
                    out.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "v":
                    out.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "w":
                    out.println("This is not yet implemented.");
                    break;
                case "q":
                    return;
                default:
                    out.println("You did not select a viable option.");
                    out.println("Try again.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't for the life of me get it to ignore what ever initial communication is happening and just wait until the user actually enters some input purposefully.

Comment: Be careful, currently your server code will not accept any connection after the 5 limit is reached, even if someone disconnect. Moreover after the 5 clients disconnected your program will terminate.

Comment: @gma - Thank you! I will fix this asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telnet client sends some bytes at the beginning of negotiation. In my case (as I tested your code) it was

255 - Marks the start of a negotiation sequence.

251 - Confirm willingness to negotiate.

Your Scanner consumes it and here is where your problem comes from. You'll probably need to handle the negotiation, so here is the [description](http://mud-dev.wikidot.com/telnet%3anegotiation) of it that I found...

**EDIT**

Of course, you can ignore the negotiation and simply consume the first two bytes. This could be done e.g. this way.

```
  try {
    // Get input from the client
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
    out.println("You have connected to the server.");
    out.println("Welcome.");
    in.readLine(); //consume first two bytes
    //the rest of your code...
```

Comment: 1. You probably should not ask another question in answer 2. But anyway the additional loop is useless, simple in.readLine() is enough...

Comment: Thank you. This solved my issue and is much better than my answer. I have accepted it. Thanks!